# Current Blockchain Size - geth and Parity?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, parity, synchronization

As of 09.09.2017, can anyone tell me the current disk space requirements of the blockchain, when using Geth and when using Parity?  Please assume invoking with no options.

Comment: wont it be same, as both Geth and Parity are just ethereum client .. 
Why you think it will be different ?

Comment: @Ajay Presumably, stone means the disk size rather than the number of blocks . There will be lots of different answers depending on the settings, and how long ago the client started.

Comment: @carver Yes I think you are right, thats why stone has mentioned date... 
and yes lot will depend upon the options passed to start the client

Comment: 10~12GB for Parity and 20~24GB for Geth. There is no need to ask this question over and over again, voting to close this as duplicate.

Comment: @Ajay different clients use different databases to store the chain, this impacts on the disk space requirements a lot.

Comment: @5chdn I think there is a good reason to ask the question again and again.  In fact I think the board should make this a sticky that updates the answer every week or two.

Comment: For Geth: https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast